# SQL, Order with multiple rows showing same Total value, how to count once?

Tags: sql, count, subquery

I have a dataset with unique Resaurant ID-s and Orders displaying over multiple rows, each Order also has a column with Total_with_VAT

If I query it like this it is counting the Total for each row, how can I modify it to only count for unique ORDER ID-s to get the accurate total?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Restaurant_ID,
  ROUND(SUM(Total__with_VAT_),2) AS Total_With_VAT
FROM rest.totals
GROUP BY Restaurant_ID
ORDER BY total_with_VAT DESC;
```

I have tried to run a subquery but it returns the same results

```
SELECT
  Restaurant_ID,
  ROUND(SUM(Total_with_VAT),2) AS Total_VAT
FROM (
  SELECT Restaurant_ID,
  SUM(Total__with_VAT_) AS Total_with_VAT
  FROM rest.totals
  GROUP BY Restaurant_ID
) AS subquery
GROUP BY Restaurant_ID
ORDER BY Total_VAT DESC;
```

Comment:  [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is denormalized as it has the total of a whole set on each row.

You need to group by order to get the `MIN` or `MAX`, then group again to sum it.

```sql
SELECT
  rt.Restaurant_ID,
  ROUND(SUM(rt.Total_with_VAT), 2) AS Total_VAT
FROM (
    SELECT
      rt.Restaurant_ID,
      rt.Order_ID
      MIN(rt.Total__with_VAT_) AS Total_with_VAT
    FROM rest.totals rt
    GROUP BY
      rt.Restaurant_ID,
      rt.Order_ID
) AS rt
GROUP BY
  rt.Restaurant_ID
ORDER BY
  Total_VAT DESC;
```